# Erasing all parts of a cinemagraph (animation) but the movement?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've got a few cinemagraphs we shot for a client. As expected they want them high quality, I'm following this tutorial to achieve that. http://cssmojo.com/animated-gif-with-a-jpg-background/

What I'm having issues with is (for lack of a better word) erasing all the still image. I started with actually erasing, but that gave me 200ish frames to change.

I tried grouping all the layer, but I was presented with the error, the pixels in a group could not be edited without merging the group. Merging the group removes all sorts of animation and masks so this doesn't work.

I tried to convert everything to a smart object, grouping it all into one smart object. I get the error the smart object is not directly editable.

Essestially what I'm looking for is an "apply to all frames" button. I want to erase everything but the animation, export that as a gif, go back and export the image and then be done with it. Please help!

*Edit; Something to note, these are video files, not frame by frame animations.

Photoshop cs6

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a Layer Mask on your entire Video Group. Or you can copy the background to the top of the animation. Either way should work.